# Neo4j select for update

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

does Neo4j support 'select for updates' ?
As means:
Locking a retrieved object to update it's properties ?

As also, is that covered with Spring Data ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.   And it should be covered by Spring Data, since this happens at a much lower level inside of the database.  Doesn't matter if you hit the database with whichever method, this should remain the same

[From the documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-locking.html):

> Default locking behavior
>
> - When adding, changing or removing a property on a node or relationship a write lock will be taken on the specific node or
>     relationship. When creating or deleting a node a write lock will be
>     taken for the specific node.
> - When creating or deleting a relationship a write lock will be taken on the specific relationship and both its nodes.
>
> The locks will be added to the transaction and released when the
>   transaction finishes.